# HBase Table Retrieval Data

Tags: scala, hbase

If I am trying to retrieve data from an HBase table using this code:

```
val get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(extracted.user.rowKey.toString))
val res = table.get(get)
```

I am not sure if the `val res = table.get(get)` line will return a result or not since a row with this row key: `extracted.socialUser.socialUserConnectionId.toString` passed to the Get constructor may not exist in the HBase table.

I am trying something like this:

```
val get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(extracted.socialUser.socialUserConnectionId.toString))
val res = table.get(get)
if (!res) {
    /* Create the row in the HBase table */
}
```

But it is giving me the error in that if statement saying: `Expression of this type result doesn't convert to type Boolean`. Is there a way I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, it appears `val res = table.get(get)` would return a type `Optional`.

Given that, you should be calling `res.isEmpty` instead of `!res`

Edit:

Better still, you could use `getOrElse` instead of `get` :

```
val res = table.getOrElse{
  // Create the row in the HBase table
}
```

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you so much for the help! That is exactly what I was looking for. Would it be better to use a Scan instead of Get on the table for searching for the row key? Since I heard Scan is more efficient.

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code looks like but if you have the required `rowKey`, then it's better to reference that with a `Get`. Unless of course you need to go through the entire Table.                                     See the accepted answer here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737212/hbase-get-vs-scan-and-in-memory-table

Comment: Oh ok. But even if I pass the rowkey to the `Get` it will still have to go through all the rows to find it correct? But I think since I know the rowkey `Get` maybe more efficient right.

Comment: No. `Get` will go to the particular row and scan will go through the the entire table if you do not have start and end `rowKey` values. In your case, knowing the `rowKey` before hand and using it in a `Get` is more efficient than scanning through the entire table.

Comment: I am not sure. I accepted it before though, not sure why it didn't show up. Just accepted it again sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. Thanks! :-)